# How do I install xampp on Windows Vista?

Tags: php

I'm a new student of PHP. How can I install xampp on Windows Vista?

Comment: Surely the [XAMPP for Windows page](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) should point you in the right direction?

Comment: Download the xampp Windows executable and run it, following on-screen instructions

Answer (score 4):

As the comments from the Stack Overflow users state before this question was migrated the [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) page contains everything you need.

### Most specficially:

1. Visit the [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) page.
2. [Download](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) the `EXE` file, and [Follow the Instructions](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#522) given - it's mostly a self-installer.
3. Then read about [How to Practice](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#5479) section for help getting the server configured.

Since you're a student, I would also consider asking your teachers/school for advice as well, in case they have any specific requirements that your server must meet.

Answer (score 0):

Also bear in mind potential Vista problems:
Quote from the XAMPP webpage:

**Why doesn't XAMPP work on Vista?**

```
User Account Control (UAC)

In the directory "C:\program files" you don't have full write privileges, even as Admin. Or you have only limited privileges (e.g. for ".\xampp\htdocs"). In this case you can't edit a file.
Solution: Raise your privileges within explorer (right click / security) or disable the user account control (UAC).

You have installed Apache/MySQL in "C:\xampp" as Windows service. But you can't start/stop the services with the "XAMPP Control Panel" or can't uninstall them.

Solution: Use the service management console from Windows or disable UAC.

Disabling the User Account Control (UAC)

To disable the UAC, use the program "msconfig". In "msconfig" go to "Tools", select "disable user account control" and verify your selection. Now you must restart Windows. At the same time, you can enable the UAC again.
```

Answer (score -2):

*Disabling the User Account Control (UAC)*

To disable the UAC, use the program "msconfig". In "msconfig" go to "Tools", select "disable user account control" and verify your selection. Now you must restart Windows. At the same time, you can enable the UAC again" - response to response.

Yeah, so if you turn off UAC with Windows Vista 32-bit as I'm using, and you are required to restart the computer for UAC to take effect. Do not wait to install XAMPP BECAUSE what will happen is if you do restart before installing XAMPP after disabling (UAC) in Control Panel and maybe disk cleanup like I did before restarting, you will not be able to open the XAMPP installation folder, and I tried reinstalling the XAMPP installation folder from many sources. I actually had to restore Windows to a previous period ... Start->Programs->Accessories->System Tools->System Restore, I think. I chose a day then restarted and opened the downloaded XAMPP file, and the installation file prompted like it normally does in Vista (dimming the screen) and prompting to accept or deny run.executable.

Maybe it was a bizarre glitch, but for some reason the system restore doesn't delete folders or change permissions like the (UAC) in Control Panel because I did not have to disable UAC again as System Restore did it without me having to do it again, I guess? Anyway that's the read/write layers of abstraction C, C++, .NET Framework for you, but good news, Windows Firewall prompted me asking if I would like to accept incoming network connections from Apache HTTP Server, and obviously I am about to click Unblock, but I don't think you can successfully install this program without disabling (UAC) to get the unblock window for Apache unless, but will run into the problems I discussed above.